# Mesh file does not open in QGIS

Tags: qgis, sms

[image]I have .2dm mesh, which is created using SMS software. When I import it into QGIS I am unable to see the area of my mesh. Last month I used to import these .2dm file without any problem.

Comment: What is SMS ? ...

Comment: Surface water modelling System from Aqua veo. it is a program to work on 3d mesh

Comment: What do you mean "Mesh file does not open in QGIS" do you get an error message? Do you see the layer in the layers panel? How are you opening it? Can you see the file in other software?

Comment: Have you tried any of the 2dm files in the MDAL distribution? https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lutraconsulting/MDAL/master/tests/data/2dm/M01_5m_002.2dm for example, which loads fine for me in QGIS 3.20

Comment: I can load my 2dm into QGIS but i am unable to see the Mesh display. But i can see the mesh layer in QGIS but not in display

Comment: What is MDAL distribution?

Comment: Please provide a small mesh as test data.

Comment: How can i attach my mesh data?

Comment: Through a link to some download service.

Comment: I think it is a bug from QGIS, I have deinstalled all the QGIS versions and reinstall only one version of it again, now it is working